# How to hide powershell script module code

Tags: powershell, encryption, module

I have created a powershell module, and some proprietary reason I don't want other users can see\change the code.

Is it possible?

*How about encrypting like we encrypt password using secure.string?*

Is any one done before...

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while back I created a [tool for wrapping a script in an exe](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/).  See if that helps.